# Updated Python to_csv output file size being magnified

Tags: python-3.x, csv, append, export-to-csv, filesize

We have a csv file that is being used like a database, and an ETL script that takes input Excel files and transforms them into the same format to append to the csv file.

The script reads the csv file into a dataframe and appends the new input dataframe to the end, and then uses to_csv to overwrite the old csv file.

The problem is, when we updated to a new version of Python (downloaded with Anaconda), the output csv file is growing larger and larger every time we append data to it. The more lines in the original csv read into the script (which gets output with the new appended data), the larger the output file size is magnified. The actual number of rows and data in the csv files are fine, it's just the file size itself that is unusually large.

Does anyone know if updating to a new version of Python could have broken this process?
Is Python storing data in the csv file that we cannot see?

Any ideas or help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Try saving the dataframe as a list of tuples and then save this list as a csv file using the Python's default `csv` module. If this resolves the issue, it means a Pandas bug.